# How to access SD-card within Aquaris E4.5 (Ubuntu edition)?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, filemanager, sd-card

I have just purchased a new bq Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu edition and I am not able to read or write on my SD-card. The smartphone recognizes the external drive, but neither the ubuntu touch file manager nor any other app gives me the opportunity to access the SD-card. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In File Manager, click the menu in the top right of the screen and choose "Unlock full access". This should ask for your passcode/pin.

[image: Menu showing 'Unlock full access' option]

Once unlocked swipe up from the bottom to reveal "Places" and you should be able to navigate to the SD Card, which may have an obscure volume label as mine does.

[image: Swiped up to reveal places]

[image: Contents of SD card]

Comment: This may sound a silly question but I have the same issue but where do I find File Manager? Many thanks

Comment: It isn't installed by default, you have to install it via the Ubuntu Store.

Comment: sure, I can find it there, but I cannot install anything from there: http://askubuntu.com/questions/827015/start-a-console-on-bq-aquaris

Comment: I restarted the device in another WiFi Network, and there I could download the file manager. really strange...