# Start a console on BQ Aquaris

Tags: ubuntu-touch, console

I would like to get on the console of my new BQ Aquaris Ubuntu Touch Pad.

Although I fund out how to get to the "Ubuntu Store" there is a "Konsole" and a "File Manager" but it seems to be nothing installable from there. It sais installing 0% although my internet is working in the browser.

I also tried download the deb file directly in firefox, but then I still cannot install it.

Is there any way to get to the console?

How do I debug my Pad?

Answer (score 0):

I finally could use the Ubuntu store after restarting the device a few times and using another WIFI in another location. This is really strange, but now I could install the "terminal" app from the store.

Anyway, I think the WiFi is not working correctly like some other basic functions, for example the screen-rotation block doesn't keep its setting: after a restart the initial orientation is kept instead.

Also very often the WiFi has no connection at all.

It is a shame, but I will send it back. Ubuntu Touch still seems not ready yet.